# Angularjs form with "name" attribute set, ignores default values

Tags: forms, validation, angularjs, angularjs-directive, default-value

To validate a form in Angularjs, the "name" attribute needs to be set on the form. When the "name" attribute is set, setting default values in the controller won't work anymore.

Here's an example to demonstrate:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Q59yBZFIGWPMveYuez52?p=preview

On the first form, I have set no "name" attribute, which will set the default value correct, but will not have a validation object when I submit the value. 
On the second form, I have set the "name" attribute, which will not set the default value correct, but will have a validation object when I submit the value.

Is this expected behavior or a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form controller is put in the `$scope` with the given name. So in your case, the name of the model collides with the name of the form and strange things happen; this is a timebomb, a bug that will haunt you sometime in the future.

I like giving forms a distinct name; if you try `<form name="user2form">` in your fiddle, it will work. (I always suffix the form name with `form` for this reason.)

Comment: Changing the form name causes the default value to be set, but the object that is submitted to my save function, is not a "validation object" that looks like this `{ "$error":{}, "$name":"user2", "$dirty":false, "$pristine":true, "$valid":true, "$invalid":false }`. When using the same form name, it does submit this type of object.

Comment: What is stopping you from doing `ng-click="save(user2form)"` if you want the `FormController`? The `user2` *model* is already accessible to `save()` from the `$scope`, but even if it wasn't, you can do `ng-click="save(user2form, user2)"` (with the obvious changes in the function too).